# omnet runtime erro

Tags: omnet++, inet, openflow

I'm trying to run SDN Multiple controllers in omnet.
I change some code in OFA_switch.cc  .. I uncommented the first section and comment the lower section of code as illustrated.
Since there is not a module "controller" but instead there is a submodule "controller" in each domain controller
I got runtime error: Error processing command OPEN_ACTIVE:remote address and port must be specified...
Can you please help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfVTb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9qwr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN87i.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to rewrite the code. It is totally fine to get that parameter from the INI file. The problem is that the remote address must be correctly specified. You can use the direct IP address there (if you know it) or it is also possible to specify a **module path** to the given node. My guess is that it is specified as `controller` which assumes that there is a module named `controller` at the top level. I assume you have put these components into submodules so the controller module is now inside a submodule. You may use `submodulename.controller` or may use relative module path something like this`^.^.controller` (I'm not sure on the exact number of (^) parent navigations. It depends on how deep the application module is inside the node.

Comment: Thanks for help. ^.^.controller should be used in ini file or in .cc file?